# python2.7 encoding issue when working with variable

Tags: python-2.7

I am having a problem with encoding within Python2.7
I have a string held within an Excel file as I believe utf-8 but when I open it within python, I can't seem to get it decode correctly

An example of the text held as utf-8:
Belo Horizonte (MG) PraÃ§a Diogo de Vasconcelos, Fundo Correio da ManhÃ£

When I copy the text into the shell, it decodes as expected:

```py
print "Belo Horizonte (MG) PraÃ§a Diogo de Vasconcelos, Fundo Correio da ManhÃ£".decode('utf-8')
Belo Horizonte (MG) Praça Diogo de Vasconcelos, Fundo Correio da Manhã
```

But when I try to use the same process on some text held in an Excel file using the following code:

```py
import xlrd, codecs
ExcelFileName= 'outfinbrazil2.xlsx'
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(ExcelFileName)
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
num_rows = worksheet.nrows
num_cols = worksheet.ncols
for curr_row in range(1, num_rows, 1):
    row_data = []
    theid = worksheet.cell_value(curr_row, 0)
    data = worksheet.cell_value(curr_row, 2)
    print data
    print data.decode('utf-8')
```

I get:

```py
Belo Horizonte (MG) PraÃ§a Diogo de Vasconcelos, Fundo Correio da ManhÃ£

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\brazil\test.py", line 15, in <module>
    print data.decode('utf-8')
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 23-24: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/unicode.html), default encoding is UTF-16LE.

Comment: Thanks but forcing the input encoding to utf-8 doesn't help  workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(ExcelFileName, encoding_override="utf-8")